# JAVA Intercept mechanism works only with CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, interceptor

I was trying to create a sample of Intercept mechanism in JAVA. The questions I have is,

1) Why it only works with injected object but not using simple constructor ?

2) How can I intercept without CDI and using constructors only ? Because I want to use constructors with some arguments (Not default constructor).

### Working code

```
    public class StartingPoint extends HttpServlet 
    {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      // With CDI
      @Inject
      SimpleGreeting greeting;

      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
      {
          System.out.println("Started");
          System.out.println(greeting.abc());
      }

    }
```

### Not working code

```
    public class StartingPoint extends HttpServlet 
    {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
      {
          // With simple constructor
          SimpleGreeting greeting = new SimpleGreeting();
          System.out.println("Started");
          System.out.println(greeting.abc());
      }

    }
```

### Other classes (Same in both cases)

SimpleGreeting.java

```
    @MyInterceptorBinding
    public class SimpleGreeting 
    {

      public SimpleGreeting()
      {

      }

      public String abc() 
      {
          return "Greet";
      }

    }
```

MyInterceptorBinding.java

```
    @Inherited
    @InterceptorBinding
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Target({ METHOD, TYPE })
    public @interface MyInterceptorBinding {
    }
```

MyInterceptor.java

```
    @Interceptor
    @MyInterceptorBinding
    public class MyInterceptor 
    {

        public MyInterceptor()
        {

        }

        @AroundInvoke
        public Object log(InvocationContext context) throws Exception 
        {
            System.out.println("Intercepted");
            return context.proceed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is with capability of intercepting  the CDI is possible . It is runtime functionality .That is why it doesn't work with normal instantiation

Comment: CDI supports even contructors with parameters, as long as those parameters are injectable. Also, you can use `@AroundConstruct` interceptors to make it intercept object creation (so basically the constructor invocaiton). And all this while still using CDI - would that help you?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the javadoc : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InterceptorBinding.html , you will notice that `@InterceptorBinding` is an annotation associated to **beans** (i.e instances managed by the container as EJB, managed beans, etc.) :

> Interceptor bindings are intermediate annotations that may be used to associate interceptors with target **beans**

Comment: I am new to CDI and annotations. Could you please elaborate it a bit in a ways how can I make it work in my example ?

Comment: I did not understand what you really want To achieve. On which class do you want to have a constructor with arguments?

Comment: Let's say on SimpleGreeting class I want have constructor with arguments, and want to instantiate greeting object using that constructor.

Comment: as @Andy Guibert said, you can not easily use Interceptor without CDI, and if you "manually" instanciate your Greeting object, you break CDI. However you can Inject CDI beans in another CDI bean using constructor injection or setter injection. Wich objects do you want to have in constructor? May be there is a way to refactor your code to make it work with. We need more information about what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why it only works with injected object but not using simple constructor ?

When the greeting is injected using CDI, there is some "magic" happening under the covers.  If CDI was only capable of calling a simple constructor, it wouldn't be a very useful technology.

So if you have the following code:

```
  @Inject
  SimpleGreeting greeting;
```

What's effectively happening under the covers is something like this:

```
SimpleGreeting greeting = injectGreeting();

private SimpleGreeting injectGreeting() {
  if ( /* MyInterceptorBinding annotation present on SimpleGreeting class */)
    new MyInterceptor().log(context); // this prints "Intercepted"
  return new SimpleGreeting();
}
```

> 2) Is there any way to intercept without CDI and using constructors only?

Technically yes, but interceptors are the easiest way.  The only other way I can think of off the top of my head is a bytecode manipulation framework such as ASM.

Comment: True, both can be different in way of implementation, But it should not change the way I use my logic. Else, what's point of convenience ?

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe it is because the interception mechanism is Proxy-base.  Which means, although you think you are referring to a `Foo`, it is actually a proxy of `Foo`, for which do the interception logic, and delegate the call to the real `Foo` instance.

   Hence the container will need to manage the injection of beans (so it can create the proxy and inject the proxy instead of the actual bean).  If you are instantiating by yourself, there is no way the container can do such work.
2. Yes there is.  For example for AspectJ, you can have runtime weaving to add those interception code into the classes in effect.